# Is there any way to control or lock the camera?

Tags: castlevania-lords-of-shadow

I just cleared the Dead Bog area and there were points where I thought I might vomit from how much the camera juts around.  Is there anyway to lock the camera or to control it manually?  I'm playing on the 360 but I'd be willing to switch platforms if there was one that offered this feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The camera shake is supposed to be a dynamic effect of the realism; there is no way to alter or minimize the shaking unfortunately.

Comment: Figures. The day when a good 3D Castlevania gets made will be the day the world ends.